My discord music bot is not playing the entire music
My discord music bot based on discord.py, yt_dlp and ffmpeg is not working.
I downloaded every module that is required and added environmental variables.
But, my discord bot is not working properly.
The bot plays the music properly at first, but the music ends before the song finishes.
Full code below:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import yt_dlp

app = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'extractaudio': True,
    'audioformat': 'mp3',
    'outtmpl': 'downloads/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'quiet': True,
}

@app.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Done')
    await app.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=None)

@app.command()
async def play(ctx, *, search: str):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = discord.utils.get(app.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if not voice_client:
        voice_client = await channel.connect()

    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{search}", download=False)['entries'][0]
        url = info['url']
        title = info['title']

    # 음악 재생
    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url, executable="ffmpeg"), after=lambda e: print("재생 완료"))
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}님이 요청하신 {title} 노래 재생 중")

@app.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice_client = discord.utils.get(app.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice_client and voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.stop()
        await voice_client.disconnect()
    
app.run('token')

I tried to add options in FFmpeg like this: options="-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5"
but it doesn't work.
I also added extra yt-dlp options.
I hope the bot properly plays the full version of music from youtube in discord.
